# Get,Put key and values from nested hashmap

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, treemap, inverted-index

I want to create a nested HashMap which returns the frequency of terms among multiple files. Like,

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> wordToDocumentMap=new HashMap<>();
```

I have been able to return the number of times a term appears in a file.

```
  Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();//for frequecy count       
   String str = "Wikipedia is a free online encyclopedia, created and edited by 
     volunteers around the world."; //String str suppose a file a.java

    // The query string
    String query = "edited Wikipedia volunteers";

    // Split the given string and the query string on space
    String[] strArr = str.split("\\s+");
    String[] queryArr = query.split("\\s+");

    // Map to hold the frequency of each word of query in the string
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (String q : queryArr) {
        for (String s : strArr) {
            if (q.equals(s)) {
                map.put(q, map.getOrDefault(q, 0) + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    // Display the map
    System.out.println(map);
```

In my code its count the frequency of the given query Individually. But I want to Map the query term and its frequency with its filenames.  I have searched around the web for a solution but am finding it tough to find a solution that applies to me. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the second hashmap supposed to contain?

Comment: @beastlyCoder 2nd hashmap is to count the terms with its frequency. **Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();//for frequecy count**

Comment: `wordToDocumentMap.put(fileName, map);`

Comment: so you want the word, and then how many times it shows up in the file

Comment: @beastlyCoder I want the query word individually with its filename. In a query, there are  3 words **edited Wikipedia volunteers**. I have been able to count each query individually, like {edited=3, Wikipedia 2, volunteers 1} and now I want to get filename with its frequecxy .

Comment: @LouisWasserman I tried it. but cannot get my expected result when I print.

Comment: @Sanzida your question is just not clear. You have a Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>. Presumably, that 'Integer' is some sort of count, one of the Strings is a filename, and the other string is a word? Which one is which? Do you want to map filenames to a mapping of word frequencies, or do you want to map a word to a mapping of 'this file contains that word this many times'?

Comment: @rzwitserloot sorry for this. I want to map filenames to a mapping of words frequency.like **<filename,<word,frequency>>**.

Comment: What is `queryArr` and `strArr`?  Why should `q` be equal to `s`?  What is the point of `s`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman In my code I splited my query string in whitespace.and my expected output like :{filename: a.java ,<String:edited,frequency:2> } then :{filename: a.java ,<String:Wikipedia,frequency:1> } ,and then :{filename: a.java ,<String:volunteers ,frequency:8> } in nested map format . but I cannot do mapping with filename

Comment: @LouisWasserman in my query there are 3 words, I searched the three words individually from a String line .queryarray is for searching the every single word from a string line.the output I get 
from the program {edited=2, wikipedia=1,volunteers=4}. and here **String str = "Wikipedia is a free online encyclopedia, created and edited by 
     volunteers around the world."** is supposed a file a.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding you correctly.

What you want is to be able to read in a list of files and map the file name to the map you create in the code above. So let's start with your code and let's turn it into a function:

```
public Map<String, Integer> createFreqMap(String str, String query) {

    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();//for frequecy count       

    // The query string
    String query = "edited Wikipedia volunteers";

    // Split the given string and the query string on space
    String[] strArr = str.split("\\s+");
    String[] queryArr = query.split("\\s+");

    // Map to hold the frequency of each word of query in the string
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (String q : queryArr) {
        for (String s : strArr) {
            if (q.equals(s)) {
                map.put(q, map.getOrDefault(q, 0) + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    // Display the map
    System.out.println(map);
    return map;
}
```

OK so now you have a nifty function that makes a map from a string and a query

Now you're going to want to set up a system for reading in a file to a string.

There are a bunch of ways to do this. You can look here for some ways that work for different java versions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/326440/9789673

lets go with this (assuming >java 11):

```
String content = Files.readString(path, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

Where path is the path to the file you want.

Now we can put it all together:

```
String[] paths = ["this.txt", "that.txt"]
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> output = new HashMap<>();
String query = "edited Wikipedia volunteers"; //String query = "hello";
for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    String content = Files.readString(paths[i], StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    output.put(paths[i], createFreqMap(content, query);
}
```

Comment: here is my query  there are three words **edited Wikipedia volunteers** . and I count its frequency individually.if my file name is a.java how can I map those three words with the filename a.java? I am a beginner.can u pls tell me the step by step procedure? thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can set the variable query to anything you want. So instead of String query = "hello"; it can be String query = "edited Wikipedia volunteers";

Comment: thanks for your feedback.sorry for the last comment. I can understand your code now correctly.